# Access and display web sourced data as 'messages' in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have data I provide on an http connection that's essentially message information.

I'd like to create an AddOn for Outlook that will consume/interface with that http service as if it were a mail source and display sender, recipient, subject, date etc and then be able to download the actual message and display it.

I envision this service being accessed either via a folder in the left-hand panel. (Uber feature would be if I could drag a message out of this service into the inbox!)

Unfortunately, I don't normally write code on the MS Stack -- I'm a linux guy. So I'm looking for either a follow-the-dots tutorial or an example of something similar. Failing that, I'll hire someone to write this so would love to know the specific skillsets I should be looking for when I contract someone to write it.

#### EDIT / Additional Thoughts

I have considered changing the web service (or at least creating a middle-man) that spoke IMAP, but only implemented a sub-set of commands (eg, there's no delete or create-folder or move)

One problem with that is that retrieving the actual message needs to be a different opperation (one that has a quota cost to the end user) so I can't just show the message. An option would be to show a "retrieve" button rather than the actual message (I found a great resource here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542625.aspx for doing something like that) and then having that button do the retrieve and then reload itself. Maybe.

Comment: +1 for ambitiousness. Interested to see whether anything comes out of it. Could turn out to be a HUGE project though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pekka says this could turn into a big project .. your description is pretty general and as you know the devil is in the detail ! but there are a number of options ..

1. you may be able to use [Folder.WebViewURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176546.aspx) Property of a folder that you have created in outlook and show your app via a web app (you can build that on any tech stack you like) 
   ok drag and drop may become a little tricky to do.
2. Outlook forms could also be used. A form can call out to your web service and display what you want. There is some info about form on SO but http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=35 is the best place.
3. Subclassing .. you can then create your own tree under the outlook tree and display whatever you want in the right hand pane such as grids forms etc. these can interact with the normal outlook folders and you can do your drag and drop though you woudl have to create Outlook Items to display them in the inbox. There is a tutorial on the technique http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/additional_panel_Outlook.aspx though not doing exactly what you want but the technique is sound.
4. Next up build your own MAPI Message Store Provider which is probally the hardest thing to do on the list.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842153.aspx

As I said your question is no functional spec and there are always many ways to skin the cat but 2 or 3 are probaly where you shoudl look at unless it simple enough just a display a web app.

Marcus

Comment: Wow .. thanks for that! You've given me four good leads to follow up. As you say, the devil is in the details, but I really had no good clue where to even start. The details will one day sort themselves out :-D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe our product could help you in order to avoid writing your own MAPI Message Store Provider. 
Kayxo Insight : [.Net Custom Framework for MAPI Message Store Provider](http://www.kayxo.com/products/ki_developers.php)